# Not able to get FullCalendar event sources to show up in different colors

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

So I have FullCaledar working...loading events from my JSON feed.  However, I am not able to get my calendars to show up in different colors.  I am using the latest version of FullCalendar files (v3.8.0).

My script is as follows...

```
<link href="../../FullCalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../FullCalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../FullCalendar/lib/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FullCalendar/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FullCalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        //url: '<my json URL>',
                        color: '#0033dd',
                        textColor: '#ffffff'
                    },
                    {
                         //url: '<my json URL>',
                        color: '#dd3300',
                        textColor: '#000000'
                    }
                ],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
            ...blah, blah, blah...
```

The events are loading from both sources...but they all show up using the color scheme of the first source.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason but not the solution.  It seems that setting the allDay property as TRUE causes the event to not display.  I have tried several different configurations and found that the event does not show up in any view with the allDay property set to true.

Once I set the allDay property to FALSE, my events started showing up.

Comment: " It seems that setting the allDay property as TRUE causes the event to not display". Only if you haven't got an "allday" section in your view, but that only applies to the agenda view, controlled by this option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/allDaySlot . The month view should still show allDay events. If that's not the case, and they don't show up in "month" view when `allDay` is `true`, then I suspect this was not the root cause of the issue. Exactly what, how and where it gets displayed depends a bit on the contents (or lack of) of the start/end dates/times you give the event as well.

Comment: Also, your answer refers to "not displaying" but the question was about all displaying in the same colour, which is not the same thing at all?